# How to find a solutions different of 0 to undertermined homogenous linear system with matlab

Tags: matlab, system, linear-algebra

I am interested in finding positive solutions to undetermined homogenous linear system.

`lsqnonneg(A,b)` works well when the system is not homogenous. In the following example `A = [1 1 0 -1 1; 0 1 1 0 1], b = [0; 0]` when I use `lsqnonneg(A,b)` the answer is `x = [0; 0; 0; 0; 0]`, however `x1 = [1; 0; 0; 1; 0]` is a nonnegative solution with not all values equal 0.

Does anybody know how could I obtain non negative solutions with at least a component different of 0?

Comment: Unless b is nonzero (non-homogeneous system), I don't think this is possible. Because the presented solution is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Homogeneous_systems) states, a homogeneous linear system has either one solution, the zero solution, or an infinite number of solutions, including the zero solution.

Since MATLAB cannot give you an infinite set of solutions, only the zero solution is presented.

Comment: and, how could I check if at least there is a completely positive solution (different of 0) in this infinite set of solutions?. I would like to know if there is a solution like [1; 0; 0; 1; 0] (completely positive), but I do not want solutions like [-1; 1; 1; -1, 0]

Comment: check if  your `x` is completely positive: `any(x < 0)`